# R studio table formatting - how to fit all columns on 1 page

Tags: r, dataframe, formatting, r-markdown

[image: see example]

I have a table that contains 15 columns. How can I fit all columns in one page?

Right now the first 12 columns are printed first. The other 3 columns are printed below the first 12 columns.

I need all columns names show on the same row.

I am using R-markdown in Rstudio.

Thank you.

Comment: What *page*...?

Comment: How can I make all column names show on the same row?

Comment: What *format* (html, pdf, text)? How wide is each column? Can you afford to truncate cell contents? Truncate column names? (So many question ...)

Comment: I am okay with html or pdf, whichever is easier. I just want it in a row. The column width can be adjusted. I posted a example.

Comment: Given the image of data you just provided, you will likely need to convert each to string, formatting/truncating each column individually. If you want more help, you may need to provide real data (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Use smaller font. Use fewer decimal places. Use landscape print layout. Use wider paper. Use wider monitor. You have options...